# Reset color cycle in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have data about 3 trading strategies, each with and without transaction costs.  I want to plot, on the same axes, the time series of each of the 6 variants (3 strategies * 2 trading costs).  I would like the "with transaction cost" lines to be plotted with `alpha=1` and `linewidth=1` while I want the "no transaction costs" to be plotted with `alpha=0.25` and `linewidth=5`.  But I would like the color to be the same for both versions of each strategy.

I would like something along the lines of:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))

for c in with_transaction_frame.columns:
    ax.plot(with_transaction_frame[c], label=c, alpha=1, linewidth=1)

****SOME MAGIC GOES HERE TO RESET THE COLOR CYCLE

for c in no_transaction_frame.columns:
    ax.plot(no_transaction_frame[c], label=c, alpha=0.25, linewidth=5)

ax.legend()
```

What is the appropriate code to put on the indicated line to reset the color cycle so it is "back to the start" when the second loop is invoked?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can reset the colorcycle to the original with [Axes.set_color_cycle](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle). Looking at the code for this, there is a function to do the actual work:

```
def set_color_cycle(self, clist=None):
    if clist is None:
        clist = rcParams['axes.color_cycle']
    self.color_cycle = itertools.cycle(clist
```

And a method on the Axes which uses it:

```
def set_color_cycle(self, clist):
    """
    Set the color cycle for any future plot commands on this Axes.

    *clist* is a list of mpl color specifiers.
    """
    self._get_lines.set_color_cycle(clist)
    self._get_patches_for_fill.set_color_cycle(clist)
```

This basically means you can call the set_color_cycle with None as the only argument, and it will be replaced with the default cycle found in rcParams['axes.color_cycle'].

I tried this with the following code and got the expected result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.arange(10) + i)

# for Matplotlib version < 1.5
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(None)
# for Matplotlib version >= 1.5
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.arange(10, 1, -1) + i)

plt.show()
```

[image: Code output, showing the color cycling reset functionality]

Comment: Thanks @8one6. Matplotlib is incredibly powerful when you know how - I think the real problem is that power doesn't document so well, so IMHO a really important skill with open source Python packages is to be able to follow the actual implementation/code. It really isn't that complex - I imagine it is just daunting to do the first time...

Comment: Since Matplotlib 1.5.0, `set_color_cycle` is deprecated and does not accept `None` anymore! Luckily, the new (broader) alternative `set_prop_cycle` *does* accept `None` still...

Comment: Setting set_prop_cycle to None also gets rid of the labels. Is there a way to only reset the colors? plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(color=None) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 41):

As the answer given by @pelson uses `set_color_cycle` and this is deprecated in Matplotlib 1.5, I thought it would be useful to have an updated version of his solution using `set_prop_cycle`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.arange(10) + i)

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(np.arange(10, 0, -1) + i)

plt.show()
```

Remark also that I had to change `np.arange(10,1,-1)` to `np.arange(10,0,-1)`. The former gave an array of only 9 elements. This probably arises from using different Numpy versions. Mine is 1.10.2.

**EDIT**: Removed the need to use `rcParams`. Thanks to @divenex for pointing that out in a comment.

Comment: Contrary to what stated in this answer `plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)` works from Matplotlib 1.5 (as pointed out by @burnpanck) and I just verified it works in Matplotlib 2.0 too.

Comment: "deprecated" means it will probably be removed in the future, even if it works in the current version. See http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_color_cycle.html

Comment: My comment is not about the deprecation, but about the fact that there is no need to specify the cycler in `set_prop_cycle`.

Comment: Sorry. You're completely right. I misread your comment. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 6):

Since you mentioned you're using seaborn, what I would recommend doing is:

```
with sns.color_palette(n_colors=3):

    ax.plot(...)
    ax.plot(...)
```

This will set the color palette to use the currently active color cycle, but only the first three colors from it. It's also a general purpose solution for any time you want to set a temporary color cycle.

Note that the only thing that actually needs to be under the `with` block is whatever you are doing to create the `Axes` object (i.e. `plt.subplots`, `fig.add_subplot()`, etc.). This is just because of how the matplotlib color cycle itself works.

Doing what you specifically want, "resetting" the color cycle, is possible, but it's a hack  and I wouldn't do it in any kind of production code. Here, though, is how it could happen:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.randn(10, 3))
ax._get_lines.color_cycle = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette())
ax.plot(np.random.randn(10, 3), lw=5, alpha=.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write up this answer.  I understand that this will work because I know a priori that I'll be plotting 3 series using each of the `ax.plot` commands above.  But do you know if there's a general way to "reset" the color cycle at a given point in code?  Without specific knowledge of what the color cycle is (or what its status is) at the point in code that command is issued?

Comment: It's possible to do, but it's a hack that I would not really recommend. See edit to answer.

Comment: I'd also point out that you should always be able to infer how many colors you need from the data.

Comment: This is very helpful (and I'll accept the answer).  While you're right that I can infer the number of lines from the context, I was hoping to keep the code more readable.  If there were literally a `reset_color_cycle` command, I think things would read very naturally.  Actually, your 1-line 'hack' above doesn't bother me too much.  Why don't you recommend its use in production?

Comment: In general you want to avoid using internal features (that by convention are methods or attributes where the name starts with a single underscore). That generally signals the API could change without warning. It's specifically a concern here because I know the matplotlib devs are talking about changing how the color cycle is implemented, and so it's possible this hack will not work on future versions of matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. Do you think this is a worthwhile feature request for matplotlib?

Answer (score 3):

Simply choose your colours and assign them to a list, then when you plot your data iterate over a [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) object containing your column and the colour you wish.

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

for col, color in zip(colors, with_transaction_frame.columns):
    ax.plot(with_transaction_frame[col], label=col, alpha=1.0, linewidth=1.0, color=color)

for col, color in zip(no_transaction_frame.columns):
    ax.plot(no_transaction_frame[col], label=col, alpha=0.25, linewidth=5, color=color)
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) creates a list that aggregates the elements from each of your lists. This allows you to iterate over both easily at the same time.

Comment: you could actually build up that list of colors by calling `get_color` on the return of `ax.plot` in the first loop.

Comment: Kind of sidesteps the question.  In my case, I'm working with `seaborn` and in general, there might be a complicated color palette default in place.  I don't want to screw with that.  I just want to plot twice with the same color cycle used each time...without needing to know what that color cycle is ahead of time.

Comment: Ok fair enough :) it's not really side-stepping the question as it's a perfectly valid and simple answer to the question as you stated it but if you're using seaborn then I can see how you wouldn't want to mess with the colors by choosing them manually. In this case I would do as @M4rtini suggests and use `get_color` to get the colors from the first plotting iteration and use them in the 2nd, possibly they may want to write that up as an answer for you.

Comment: Somehow i am not able to edit your answer, but could you insert a commata in `colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the colors from seaborn like this: `colors = sns.color_palette()`.  Ffisegydd's answer would then work great.  You could also get the color to plot using the modulus/remainder operater (%): `mycolor = colors[icolumn % len(colors]`.  I use often use this approach myself.  So you could do:

`for icol, column in enumerate(with_transaction_frame.columns):
    mycolor = colors[icol % len(colors]
    ax.plot(with_transaction_frame[col], label=col, alpha=1.0, color=mycolor)`

Ffisegydd's answer may be more 'pythonic', though.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the already excellent answers, you can consider using a colormap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cmap = plt.cm.viridis

datarange = np.arange(4)

for d in datarange:
    # generate colour by feeding float between 0 and 1 to colormap
    color = cmap(d/np.max(datarange)) 
    plt.plot(np.arange(5)+d, c=color)

for d in datarange:
    # generate colour by feeding float between 0 and 1 to colormap
    color = cmap(d/np.max(datarange))
    plt.plot(-np.arange(5)+d, c=color)
```

[image]