# Families of curves with different seaborn palettes in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In my python program I  have three families of curves to each I want to assign a seaborn colour palette and plot them all into one single plot.

My solution so far is the following code.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
volt = np.zeros(N)
states = np.zeros([6,N])

for k in range(1,4):
    if k == 1:
        sns.set_palette('Blues_d',6)
    if k == 2:
        sns.set_palette('BuGn_d',6)
    if k == 3:
        sns.set_palette('Oranges_d',6)

    for i in range(N):
        j = -1 + 2*float(i)/N
        volt[i] = j*(mu[1]-mu[0])
        state = evolve(s, ss, PP, beta, float(k) * D / 3, B, j * mu, tmax)

        for j in range(6):
            states[j,i] = state[j]

    for i in range(6):
        y = np.zeros(N)

        for j in range(N):
            y[j] = states[i,j]
        plt.plot(volt,y)

plt.show()
```

However, the plot always ends up being rendered in the first palette 'Blues_d'. How can I change the code, so that the first family of curves is plotted with 'Blues_d', the second with 'BuGn_d' and the third with 'Oranges_d' but in the same figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question (in part because your code is not quite a minimum working example), but if you're going to be using `seaborn` then it is probably in your best interest to start handling your data with `pandas`. A lot of `seaborn` is written with `pandas` in mind and so the two jive really well. Plotting with multiple color palettes is one such example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_style('whitegrid')

x = np.linspace(0, 3, 31)

U_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'u1': 2.6*x**2 - 4.5,
    'u2': 2.5*x**2 - 4.9,
    'u3': 2.3*x**2 - 4.7}, index=x)

V_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'v1': -5.1*x + 11,
    'v2': -4.9*x + 10,
    'v3': -5.5*x + 12}, index=x)

W_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'w1': -6.5*(x-1.6)**2 + 9.1,
    'w2': -6.2*(x-1.8)**2 + 9.5,
    'w3': -6.1*(x-1.5)**2 + 9.7}, index=x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

U_df.plot(ax=ax, color=sns.color_palette('Blues_d', 3))
V_df.plot(ax=ax, color=sns.color_palette('BuGn_d', 3))
W_df.plot(ax=ax, color=sns.color_palette('Oranges_d', 3))

ax.legend(ncol=3, loc='best')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a bunch! I have now found a solution to my problem using your method.

Comment: @ThomasWening Great! If it solved your problem you can consider marking my answer as correct and/or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [How to use multiple colormaps in seaborn on same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894800/how-to-use-multiple-colormaps-in-seaborn-on-same-plot) will be usefull. Try answer from mwaskom:

```
pal1 = sns.color_palette('rainbow', sum(ix1))
pal2 = sns.color_palette('coolwarm', sum(ix2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
ax.scatter(x_data[ix1], y[ix1], c=pal1, s=60, label="smaller")
ax.scatter(x_data[ix2], y[ix2], c=pal2, s=60, label="larger")
ax.legend(loc="lower right", scatterpoints=5)
```

That is,
extract the palette and pass it to the plotting function.
Hope this is useful.