# How to control the color of graph lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, graph

I have a following data frame of paths, (x,y) points belonging to the same "uid" is considered to be one separate path.

```
   uid        x       y
 0  5          1       1
 1  5          2       1
 2  5          3       1
 3  5          4       1
 4  21         4       5 
 6  21         6       6
 7  21         5       7
 8  25         1       1
 9  25         2       2
10  25         3       3
11  25         4       4
12  25         5       5
13  27         1       3
14  27         2       3
15  27         4       3
```

Following is the code I am using to plot each of these paths:

```
%matplotlib notebook

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
df.groupby("uid").plot(kind='line', x = "x", y = "y", ax = ax)
plt.title("Paths")

#ax.legend_.remove()

plt.show()
```

Since, matplotlib auto generates the color for each line in the graph, I want to control the color of the paths generated from my df based on their **"uid"**.

Suppose I want to keep the color of the path generated for **uid=25** and **uid=27** **only** to be **green** and the rest of them to be black.

Also, I want to change the **"kind"** of line for uid=25,27 to be **dotted** while all others should be simple line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it as a loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("data.txt", sep=" ")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

color = ["k", "g"]
line = ["solid", "dotted"]
for (key, gr) in df.groupby("uid"):
    if key == 25 or key == 27:
        i = 1
    else:
        i = 0
    gr.plot(linestyle=line[i], x="x", y="y", ax=ax, color=color[i], label=key)
plt.title("Paths")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the above df is not just limited to four id's, my actual data frame has 100's of paths, I want all the lines to be of same color except a few ids to be of specific color, like in above example path generated for uid 25 and 27 should **only** be Green while rest of them should be black.

Comment: @Liza I edited David's post with the correct solution, so it should be visible as soon as he or someone with the proper authority approves it.

Comment: @Hami Thank you sooo much. But if no one approves it anytime soon, please kindly post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Liza see the post now.

Comment: Hi @Liza, I included the last bit of info about the line style (solid versus dotted).

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidJaimes