# matplotlib retrieve color from plt.plot command

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How to obtain the color used by plt.plot after calling it? 
I dont want to specify the color in advance.

```
def plotStuff():

    lines = plt.plot(np.random.rand(500))
    color = lines.magic_thing_get_color
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(500),color = color,label = "_nolegend_" )
```

So calling plotStuff twice would use one color to plot 2 things the first time and a different color when calling it the second time.

Comment: instead of retrieving it, it might be easier to set the color cycle in advance. related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24193174/2096752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *magic function* you are searching is `get_color()`. However, the plot command returns a list with the lines objects and thus, you have to call this function on the items and not the list itself. Your function could look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def plotStuff():
    lines = plt.plot(np.random.rand(20))
    color = lines[0].get_color()
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(20),color = color,label = "_nolegend_" )
plotStuff()
```

creating a plot like
[image]
with both lines having the same color.