# Python gaussian fit with same color as bars of histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, data-fitting, gauss

I use the functions `plot()` and `hist()` from **pyplot** (without any color definition) to generate the following graphic:

[image: Plot of two data sets, with each having an own gauss fit]

There will be even more data sets included. That's why I want to use the same color for fit curve and the related histogram, to keep it somewhat distinguishable.

I couldn't find anything related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using

```
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(None)
```

Thanks to [Reset color cycle in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193174/reset-color-cycle-in-matplotlib)

The following code should work out of the box to complete my question regarding gaussian fit with same color as bars of histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

list_of_lists = []

for i in range(2):
    list = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
    list = list.tolist()
    list_of_lists.append(list)

plt.figure()
plt.hist(list_of_lists, bins = 10, normed=True)

numb_lists = len(list_of_lists)

plt.gca().set_color_cycle(None)

for i in range(0, numb_lists):
    list = list_of_lists[i][:]
    mean = np.mean(list)
    variance = np.var(list)
    sigma = np.sqrt(variance)
    x = np.linspace(min(list), max(list), 100)
    plt.plot(x, mlab.normpdf(x, mean, sigma))
```

Answer (score 1):

to make sure the plot and the histogram have the same colour, my suggestion is that you fix the colour for the plot and for the best fit line.
If you look at the example here http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html
and then at the python documentation for pyplot http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

the matplotlib.pyplot.hist method has a kwarg  color that allows you to choose the colour you want for the histogram. In the example they set facecolor='green'

Then for the best fit line, you can choose to plot it in the same colour. I would need to see the code to give more precise indications. However if we go back to the example here the line properties are set:

```
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)
```

so if we wanted the fit line to be green like the rest of the histogram we would use:

```
l = plt.plot(bins, y, 'r--', linewidth=1, color = 'green')
```

Hope this helps, can't give you more specific tips if you don't post any lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. And also sorry for the lack of code. I' ll correct that immediately