# How do I plot two pandas DataFrames in one graph with the same colors but different line styles?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3),columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3),columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()
```

[image: df2 plot]

[image: df1 plot]

My question is that, how can I plot them in one graph such that:

1. The three series of df1 and df2 are still in the same blue, orange
   and green lines **as above**.
2. The three series of df1 are in solid lines
3. The three series of df1 are in dashed lines

Currently the closest thing I can get is the following:

```
ax = df1.plot(style=['b','y','g'])
df2.plot(ax=ax, style=['b','y','g'], linestyle='--')
```

[image]

Is there any way to get the color codes used by default by DataFrame.plot()? Or is there any other better approach to achieve what I want? Ideally I don't want to specify any color codes with the `style` parameter but always use the default colors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without messing with the colors themselves or transferring them from one plot to the other you may easily just [reset the colorcycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116381/4124317) in between your plot commands

```
ax = df1.plot()
ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
df2.plot(ax=ax, linestyle="--")
```

Comment: Nice! This is a new method I will commit to memory for matploblib.  Thanks, IOBE! +1

Answer (score 8):

You could use `get_color` from the lines:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3),columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3),columns=['A','B','C']).cumsum()

ax = df1.plot()
l = ax.get_lines()
df2.plot(ax=ax, linestyle='--', color=(i.get_color() for i in l))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Scott Boston, I have posted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445131/comparing-values-from-two-datasets . If you could have a look at mine too, it would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to follow your answer and other answers, but unfortunately I am still having difficulties in getting a good output (because of colours, lines and legend). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You can get the default color parameters that are currently being used from matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = list(plt.rcParams.get('axes.prop_cycle'))

[{'color': '#1f77b4'},
 {'color': '#ff7f0e'},
 {'color': '#2ca02c'},
 {'color': '#d62728'},
 {'color': '#9467bd'},
 {'color': '#8c564b'},
 {'color': '#e377c2'},
 {'color': '#7f7f7f'},
 {'color': '#bcbd22'},
 {'color': '#17becf'}]
```

so just pass `style=['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c']` and the colors should work.

If you want to set another color cycler, say the older version, then:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = ("cycler('color', 'bgrcmyk')")
list(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
#[{'color': 'b'},
# {'color': 'g'},
# {'color': 'r'},
# {'color': 'c'},
# {'color': 'm'},
# {'color': 'y'},
# {'color': 'k'}]
```

Comment: You can also get just the keys rather than a list of dictionaries, and plot them with seaborn! `sns.palplot(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])`

Comment: Ah that's smarter, I guess you don't really need the dictionary in this case

Comment: Thank you ALollz. What does `list('bgrcmyk')` do? If I remove it and it will still returns the same result. And based on what I read in this page (https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-color-cycles-and-color-maps) it is the 7 colors of the old version, which is no the 10 colors returned.

Comment: @Jimbo you're right, that didn't seem to be doing anything. It's still just listing the default. I'll update that, and show how you could set and get the colors for the old version.