# Plotting values from two datasets for comparison

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot two dataframes in order to compare the results. My first choice would be to plot line charts based only on one column from the two dataframes.

```
df
       Name Surname P   R   F   
    0   B   N   0.41    0.76    0.53
    1   B   L   0.62    0.67    0.61
    2   B   SV  0.63    0.53    0.52
    3   B   SG  0.43    0.61    0.53
    4   B   R   0.81    0.51    0.53
    5   T   N   0.32    0.82    0.53
    6   T   L   0.58    0.69    0.62
    7   T   SV  0.67    0.61    0.64
    8   T   SG  0.53    0.63    0.57
    9   T   R   0.74    0.48    0.58
```

and

```
data = [['B','N',0.41,0.72,0.51], 
['B','L',0.66,0.67,0.62],
['B','SV',0.63,0.51,0.51],
['B','SG',0.44,0.63,0.51],
['B','R',0.81,0.51,0.62],
['T','N',0.33,0.80,0.47],
['T','L',0.58,0.61,0.63],
['T','SV',0.68,0.61,0.64],
['T','SG',0.53,0.63,0.57],
['T','R',0.74,0.48,0.58]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Surname','P','R','F'])
```

I would like to create a plot based on F values, keeping information (in legend/labels) of B/T and R,N,L, SV, SG.

I have tried with bar charts, but this does not take into account labels/legend.

I am looking for something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

df.plot(x="Name", y=["F"], ax=ax)
df1.plot(x="Name", y=["F"], ax=ax2, ls="--")
```

However this misses labels and legend.

I have also tried with:

```
ax = df.plot()
l = ax.get_lines()
df1.plot(ax=ax, linestyle='--', color=(i.get_color() for i in l))
```

But I cannot distinguish by Name, Surname and dataframe (on the x axis there should be Surname).
It would be also ok to plot separately the values (P, R and F) as follows:

```
ax = df[['P']].plot()
l = ax.get_lines()
df1[['P']].plot(ax=ax, linestyle='--', color=(i.get_color() for i in l))
```

I should compare F values of the two plots based on Name and Surname.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `fig.legend` maybe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to add information about other parameters to a graph is to use functions like ax.text or ax.annotate over a loop. The code should look like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data1 = ax.bar(20*index, df["F"], bar_width)
data2 = ax.bar(20*index+bar_width, df1["F"],bar_width)

for i in index:
    ax.text(i*20-5,0,df['Surname'][i],)
    ax.text(i*20-5,0.05,df['Name'][i])
    ax.text(i*20+bar_width-5,0,df1['Surname'][i])
    ax.text(i*20+bar_width-5,0.05,df1['Name'][i])
plt.show()
```

[image: Image generated by the code]

Useful link:
[Official Documentation for Text in Matplotlib Plots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/text_intro.html)

**Edit:**
Probably similar problem: [Different text at each point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point)

**Edit 2:**
Code without index:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data1 = ax.plot(df["F"])
data2 = ax.plot(df1["F"])

for i in range(1,10):
    ax.text(i,df["F"][i],df['Name'][i]+" "+df['Surname'][i],)
    ax.text(i,df["F"][i],df['Name'][i]+" "+df['Surname'][i],)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Val the former error is coming because you probably haven't defined a variable named index that is used for plotting. You could use something like index = np.arange(n)*bar_width*2 where n is the length of your data(10 in your case) and also define bar_width as the width of the bars. There is no separate feature in matplotlib to get the legend in a separate window. I suggest you shift the text to wherever you want. If you want the legend in the same window, refer to https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html . If something doesn't work you can ask again!

Comment: index stores the x values of the orange bars. But if you're using line graphs, you can remove index from the code and the code becomes data1 = plt.plot(df["F"]);data2 = plt.plot(df1["F"]). And this other error you mention, what was the error message?

Comment: @Val my code uses the variable 'index' in lines 2,3 and 5. You either need to define it or remove it from the code to avoid the error.

Comment: You can set the color and/or shape parameter differently for each line. Check the docs out https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html for exact usage.

Comment: So I cannot add any legend (for example orange line = 'df1' , blue line = 'df'), can I?

Comment: yeah you can. its just a different function: ax.legend(). Documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

df.plot(x="Name", y=["F"], ax=ax)
df1.plot(x="Name", y=["F"], ax=ax2, ls="--")
fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Output:

[image]